# ruby update with rvm error message (rvm requirements fails)

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am new to ruby and I am trying to update to the latest stable version of ruby using rvm. I get the following error message:

```
 Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
    Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
    Checking requirements for osx.
    Installing requirements for osx.
    Updating system......
    Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.1.2',
    showing last 15 lines of /Users/...../.rvm/log/1403454982_ruby-2.1.2/update_system.log
        https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
    and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
    ++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
    ++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
    ++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
    ++ case "$1" in
    ++ [[ -t 2 ]]
    ++ return 1
    ++ printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
        https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
    and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
    Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
        https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
    and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
    ++ return 1
    Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
    unknown:~ $
```

As far as I know I have rvm and homebrew installed. The following command line gives a completely different message.

```
unknown:~ ...........$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --auto-dotfiles
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/........./.rvm/
    Removing rvm PATH line from /Users/........./.profile /Users/........./.zshrc.
    Adding rvm PATH line to /Users/........./.profile /Users/........../.bashrc /Users/........./.zshrc.
touch: /Users/........../.bashrc: Permission denied
/Users/........./.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/functions/installer: line 1107: /Users/......../.bashrc: Permission denied
    Removing rvm loading line from /Users/......../.bash_profile /Users/......./.zlogin.
    Adding rvm loading line to /Users/......./.bash_profile /Users/......./.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/......../.rvm/ is complete.

# ,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.


rvm 1.25.27 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.1.2',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/........../.rvm/log/1403455327_ruby-2.1.2/update_system.log
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  115 > rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  73 > case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  78 > case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > [[ -t 2 ]]
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > return 1
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  117 > printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew : requirements_osx_brew_update_system()  377 > return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
unknown:~ $
```

Sorry if its long but I can't find the answer anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The following command line gives a completely different message.

Here are the error messages:

First error message:

> Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
>           https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
>       and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'

Second error message:

> Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
>       https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'

So it looks like it's an *installing homebrew problem*.  I would think that going to the link given, and reading about the common issues encountered when updating homebrew would be something to try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, did you try to run it with sudo?

```
sudo rvm install ruby-2.1.2
```